# MongoDB relational storage concepts

Tags: mongodb, rest, jsonschema

Suppose I have the following schemas ( I've stripped down the properties to make the question easier to explain ):

## Blog

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "required": true
        },
        "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 6,
            "maxLength": 128,
            "required": true
        },
        "body": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 6,
            "maxLength": 128,
            "required": true
        },
        "author": {
            "$ref": "schema/user.json#",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

## User

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "required": true
        },
        "username": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        },
        "handle": {
            "type": "string",
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

It seems as though my only choices, in regards to storing this in a MongoDB collection are to either store a full version of the Blog, including a full representation of the User within it, or using Mongo's reference abilities to include the reference.

The advantage of the full representation is that I can get everything I want in one query, but it seems at the expense/disadvantage of possibly having inaccurate information that you would want to include in a template ( IE the User's handle was updated after the Blog entry was stored ).

The advantage of the reference approach is that you have accurate data, but at the expense/disadvantage of the "performance decline" I keep reading about due to the overhead of the additional query.

My specific questions, that I can't seem to find in any of the similar questions on StackOverflow, or on Google searches are:

1. Does anyone have an actual set of data from performance tests they've done that actually shows the performance of the references being that big of a hit? I know I could test this myself, but I figure rather than dumping 3-4 hours into building out variations of code, if someone already had reliable data on this, I'd use that.
2. Is the common alternative to references to just be constantly updating collections that hold other properties when one is updated? Specifically, if a User is updated, find all Blog's ( and other Model's that contain a User ) that have a User property, fetch the documents that have the User who was updated, and then update them all to match to updated document?
3. In the case of an API implementation, is there a "standard" on what level of properties are considered "update-able". Specifically, if someone PUT's a Blog ( for update ), but that Blog has a User property with information different than the one directly in the User collection, is it expected that the User collection is then updated with the new information ( possibly triggering the logic in #2 back to other Blog entries )?